# How to know the real column and row index of a html table with merged row or column

Tags: jquery, merge, cell

Please see a demo here. http://jsfiddle.net/wgstudio/CqNfZ/2/

I want merge cell(0,0) and cell(1,0) in a html talbe, it works on a regular table.

The code isbelow.

```
        function() {
            var table = $("#table1");

            var rowIndex = 0;
            var colIndex = 0;                
            var actionCell =$($(table.children().children()[rowIndex]).children()[colIndex]); //Cell1
            var tr = table.children().children()[rowIndex + 1]; 
            var toBeRemoved = $($(tr).children()[colIndex]);//Cell4
            toBeRemoved.remove();
            rowSpan = toBeRemoved.attr("rowSpan") == undefined ? 1 : parseInt(toBeRemoved.attr("rowSpan"), 10);
            actionCell.attr("rowspan", (actionCell.attr("rowSpan") == undefined ? 1 : parseInt(actionCell.attr("rowSpan"), 10)) + rowSpan);
        }
```

but if the table is like this:

```
    <table id="table2" style=" width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">cell_1</td>
            <td rowspan="2">cell_2cell_5</td>
            <td>cell_3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell_6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>cell_7</td>
            <td>cell_8</td>
            <td>cell_9</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

(0,0) (0,1) are merged cells, when I want to merge (0,0)"Cell1" and (2,0)"Cell7", how can I find "cell 7" via js code?

Hope I explain it clear.

Thank you very much.

Bill

Comment: how will this work from user perspective in a more real world environment? Your simplified demo is only going to work for first and second rows. Can give you more versatile solution if underrstand how it will be implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you are encountering is that once a rowspan is added to a cell, it throws off row indexing. If a cell in a row has `rowspan=3` the `row index` for the next cell in same column is `currentRowIndex + 3`.

Here's a pretty good start for what you need.

```
$("#button2").click(function() {
    /* hard code a cell to start with*/
    var actionCell = $('td:first');

    var toBeRemoved = findNextCell(actionCell);

    combineSpans( actionCell, toBeRemoved)

    /* remove merged*/
    toBeRemoved.remove();

});

function combineSpans( actionCell, toBeRemoved){
    var actionSpans = getCellSpans(actionCell);
    var nextSpans = getCellSpans(toBeRemoved);
    /* add colspan and rowspan for both cells to apply to actionCell*/
    var newSpans = {
        rowspan: actionSpans.rowSpan + nextSpans.rowSpan,
        colspan: actionSpans.colSpan + nextSpans.colSpan
    }
     /* adjust actionCell colspan/rowspan*/
    actionCell.attr(newSpans);

}

function findNextCell($cell) {

    var cellIndex = $cell.index();
    var rowSpan = $cell.attr("rowspan") || 1;
    var rowIndex = $cell.closest('tr').index();
    var nextRow = $cell.closest('table').find('tr').eq(1 * rowSpan + rowIndex);
    return nextRow.find('td').eq(cellIndex);

}


function getCellSpans($cell) {
    var obj = {}
    obj.rowSpan = parseInt($cell.attr("rowspan") || 1, 10);
    obj.colSpan = parseInt($cell.attr("colspan") || 1, 10);
    return obj;

}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/CqNfZ/7/

**EDIT**: just realized that my `combineSpans` logic needs modification. Adding 2 cells `colspan` together will cause problems

Comment: Hi charlietfl, my demo code is also hard coded to try to make my ask  easy to be understood. And your answer really help me a lot. thank you very much and happy new year! : )