# Any colspan-agnostic column index?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any way to obtain column location relative to actual table layout?

`celllindex` returns the cell number of current cell, but if previous cell was expanded through colspan, or above cell pushed in before current through rowspan, it will not take it into account.
The below image shows what desired values for this "special row/column index" I'd like to receive. In reality, the celllindex of cell (3,1) would be 1 instead of desired 3, or for cell (2,2) - 1 instead of 2).

Iterating over cells of given row to add up number of cells and their (colspan-1) is insufficient because cells above with their rowspan can push in. Currently it's done using maths on pixel positions (the column widths are uniform) but this will obviously fail in a number of cases.

Any smart suggestions?

[image: desired indices]

Comment: Maybe this is what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032023/how-to-know-the-real-column-and-row-index-of-a-html-table-with-merged-row-or-col